# add husky pre-commit hook with npm@6 on windows

Tags: husky

**Environment:**

- git version 2.25.1.windows.1
- node 12.x
- Npm 6.14.11
- husky 7.0.4
- windows 10

How to correctly setup husky & pre-commit hook? In my case I just want to add `npm test` script to run, so with every commit tests are run.

Answer (score 5):

Although most of things are covered [in docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) (if not all), I will share steps which I took in order to make this work because I have put several hours effort before finally made it.

1. `npm i husky -D`
2. add new script to `package.json` - `"prepare": "husky install"`
3. execute `npm run prepare` -> .husky folder is created in project root directory

[image]

4. add new script in `package.json` file (read more in **additional** at the bottom):

- "husky": "node ./node_modules/husky/lib/bin.js"

5. run `npm run husky add ./husky/pre-commit "npm test"` -> `pre-commit` hook is created

[image]

6. execute `git commit`
   [image]

---

**ADDITIONAL** explanation to step 4:

`npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm test"` - this is command stated in docs and many stackoverflow questions/github issues or blogs, but this doesn't work by default on Windows & npm@6 (at least not for me).

Output after this command is like this, it is just showing how to use command, no pre-commit file is created inside .husky folder:

[image]

It is documented in `husky` [docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=create-a-hook) how this can be approached differently, and that is what I tried to do in step 4.

> For Windows users, if you see the help message when running npx husky
> add ..., try node node_modules/.bin/husky add ... instead. This isn't
> an issue with husky code and is fixed in recent versions of npm 8.

- And that is all. No additional actions, nor I didn't have to unset git config core.hooksPath.

Comment: Your add script shouldn't include the thing to add, then it's not at all reusable and you might as well leave it out. Also why use ts-node?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Valid point - one way is to rename script to `husky:add:precommit`, so it makes more sense. As for `ts-node` i copy/paste it from `typeorm` script which uses same notation when migration-related commands are executed (in typescript) - but here we don't have typescript (only `.js` file from node_modules/husky/lib) so we can get rid of it. I will edit the answer.

Comment: But that's still a script you wouldn't leave in, because you're _never going to run it again_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe mhm, I get you now. What is the idea then, what do you propose?

Comment: You just include the first part `npm run husky add`, so next time you need to add a hook you can actually reuse it. Or leave it out entirely, `npm run husky` is the reusable part.

Comment: @jonrsharpe nice, thanks for mentioning these points :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I need your help. I am using npx husky add "cmd" command in prepare script. Bcz of which every npm install add same command in the pre-commit file again and again. Pls suggest me some solution.

Comment: @Raj _"I am using npx husky add "cmd" command in prepare script"_ - the solution is _don't do that_. You only add a given command _once_, it shouldn't be in your scripts at all.